pandas data validation using lamda function
I have created a pandas dataframe, my logic is if column 'a' has the value yes and column 'b' has the value 0 then generate a random number between 1,15. I am trying to use the below lamda function i seem to be getting an error
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes','Yes'], 'b': [1, 0, 0,0]})
print(df)
df['b'].apply(lambda x: random.randint(1,15) if x.a == 'Yes' and x ==0  else x)

Input
     a  b
0  Yes  1
1   No  0
2  Yes  0
3  Yes  0

My expectation is
     a  b
0  Yes  1
1   No  0
2  Yes  12
3  Yes  5


Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word traceback. You can surround the report with 3 before and 3 after to properly format the output.

Please Note:  The first error in code provided is caused by fact the 'a' column and 'b' columns are not the same length.  Please edit your question to also fix this error

You need to use apply on the whole dataframe and also change the axis to 1-> df.apply(lambda, axis=1). if you have more columns than those two, use df[['a', 'b']]

Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what do you want to ask? Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask]. If you want to ask about the error, you'll need to include it.

use np.where
import numpy as np
cond = df['a'].eq('Yes') & df['b'].eq(0)
df['b'] = np.where(cond, np.random.randint(1, 16, len(df)), df['b'])

df:
     a   b
0  Yes   1
1   No   0
2  Yes  12
3  Yes  14


Why np.where() when you can use Series.mask()? df['b'].mask(cond, np.random...)

If you want to keep to your apply approach rather than the other ways suggested, then the corrected code would be:
df['b'] = df.apply(
    (lambda x: random.randint(1, 15) if x.a == 'Yes' and x.b == 0 else x.b),
    axis=1)

